# Why does windows login hang up on "Applying Computer Settings" for 3-5 minutes

Tags: windows-xp, login, virtualization

I have a server that hosts about 20 virtual machines. The VM's all use Windows XP. When you log in to any of them after booting them up, it will take about 3-5 minutes to log you in and freeze up on "Applying Computer Settings". If you just log out and log back in however, it will log you in quickly as if your info is stored somewhere. I believe this is an issue with Group Policy settings being applied and taking a while for some reason. I looked at the USERENV.log but it is filled with symbols and is illegible (This is another issue, any ideas about that?) I think that log could be helpful if I could get it to work.

Comment: are your profiles being deleted on logoff?

Comment: Run a Group policy results wizard against the machine.  Figure out which policies are being applied.  Temporarily disable all of them.  See if it is still slow.  If not, add them back a bit a time until you find the problem policy.

Comment: I have tried a few more things to troubleshoot this, I have created a new OU in Active Directory with no inherited Group Policies, I tested placing one of the VM's in this OU and it was still slow to login. Does that rule out Group Policies as the cause, or is that not definitive proof? How do I run the Group Policy Results Wizard.

Comment: Also, in response to tony, I don't believe the profiles are deleted at logoff as I can go to Documents and Settings and see 30 + user folders there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't call it an ISSUE per se, but it's probably caused by the machine having to load the user profile, and then create a local copy and configure the applications to use that profile. The second time you log in, there's already a profile saved on a local copy, so it doesn't need to create that again.

Comment: but is there anything that can be done to shorten the time it takes? or find out specific tasks that are taking so long?

Comment: If it is windows xp you can run bootvis and get a look at what might be happening. Procmon might be able to help also. It also sounds like it might be lagging due to having to create a profile or copy it from the server to the local machine. How large is your default profile?